# How to correctly separate the ViewModel and ViewController in RAC MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I've just started updating my ReactiveCocoa app to use the MVVM pattern and have a few questions regarding the boundary between the ViewController and ViewModel and how dumb the ViewController should be.

The first part of the app I am updating is the login flow, which behaves as follows.

- User enters an email address, password and touches the login button
- A successful response contains one or more `User` models
- These `User` models are displayed along with a logout button
- A `User` model must be selected for the session before the login view is closed and the main view is presented.

**Before MVVM**

- `LoginViewController` directly handles the `LoginButton` command
- `LoginButton` command talks directly to the `SessionManager`
- `LoginViewController` displays a `UIActionSheet` for selecting a `User` model or logging out
- The user selection and logout functions of the `LoginViewController` talk directly to the `SessionManager`

**After MVVM**

- `LoginViewModel` exposes a login command and user selection and logout methods
- `LoginViewModel` user selection and logout methods talk directly to the `SessionManager`
- `LoginViewController` reacts to the login command of the `LoginViewModel`
- `LoginViewController` displays a `UIActionSheet` for selecting a `User` model or logging out
- The user selection and logout functions of the `LoginViewController` talk to the `LoginViewModel`

**LoginViewModel.h**

```
@interface LoginViewModel : RVMViewModel

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) RACCommand *loginCommand;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) RACSignal *checkingSessionSignal;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *users;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *password;

- (void)logout;
- (void)switchToUserAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;

@end
```

**LoginViewModel.m**

```
@implementation LoginViewModel

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        @weakify(self);

        // Set up the login command
        self.loginCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[self loginEnabled]
                                                    signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
            @strongify(self);
            [[[SessionManager sharedInstance] loginWithEmail:self.email
                                                    password:self.password]
             subscribeNext:^(NSArray *users) {
                 self.users = users;
             }];

            return [RACSignal empty];
        }];

        // Observe the execution state of the login command
        self.loggingIn = [[self.loginCommand.executing first] boolValue];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)logout {
    [[SessionManager sharedInstance] logout];
}

- (void)switchToUserAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < [self.users count]) {
        [[SessionManager sharedInstance] switchToUser:self.users[index]];
    }
}

- (RACSignal *)loginEnabled {
    return [RACSignal
            combineLatest:@[
                RACObserve(self, email),
                RACObserve(self, password),
                RACObserve(self, loggingIn)
            ]
            reduce:^(NSString *email, NSString *password, NSNumber *loggingIn) {
                return @([email length] > 0 &&
                         [password length] > 0 &&
                         ![loggingIn boolValue]);
            }];
}

@end
```

**LoginViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    @weakify(self);

    // Bind to the view model
    RAC(self.controlsContainerView, hidden) = self.viewModel.checkingSessionSignal;
    RAC(self.viewModel, email) = self.emailField.rac_textSignal;
    RAC(self.viewModel, password) = self.passwordField.rac_textSignal;
    self.loginButton.rac_command = self.viewModel.loginCommand;
    self.forgotPasswordButton.rac_command = self.viewModel.forgotPasswordCommand;

    // Respond to the login command execution
    [[RACObserve(self.viewModel, users)
     skip:1]
     subscribeNext:^(NSArray *users) {
         @strongify(self);

         if ([users count] == 0) {
             [Utils presentMessage:@"Sorry, there appears to be a problem with your account."
                         withTitle:@"Login Error"
                             level:MessageLevelError];
         } else if ([users count] == 1) {
             [self.viewModel switchToUserAtIndex:0];
         } else {
             [self showUsersList:users];
         }
     }];

    // Respond to errors from the login command
    [self.viewModel.loginCommand.errors
     subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         [Utils presentMessage:@"Sorry, your login credentials are incorrect."
                     withTitle:@"Login Error"
                         level:MessageLevelError];
     }];
}

- (void)showUsersList:(NSArray *)users {
    CCActionSheet *sheet = [[CCActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Organization"];

    // Add buttons for each of the users
    [users eachWithIndex:^(User *user, NSUInteger index) {
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:user.organisationName block:^{
            [self.viewModel switchToUserAtIndex:index];
        }];
    }];

    // Add a button for cancelling/logging out
    [sheet addCancelButtonWithTitle:@"Logout" block:^{
        [self.viewModel logout];
    }];

    // Display the action sheet
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}

@end
```

**Questions**

1. Creating the additional ViewModel layer means I need to proxy the `SessionManager` calls. I guess the benefit of decoupling the `LoginViewController` from the `SessionManager` outweighs the additional code and function calls of the ViewModel layer?
2. The `LoginViewController` has knowledge of the `User` model in order to display a list of users which can be selected. This breaks the MVVM pattern and certainly doesn't feel right. Should the `LoginViewModel` extract only the necessary properties of a `User` model required by the `LoginViewController` and add them to a dictionary, an array of which is returned to the `LoginViewController`? Or would it be better to have a method on the `LoginViewModel` which returns the name of a user given an index, allowing the `LoginViewController` to display this name? I understand the ViewModel is responsible for bridging the gap between the model and the view however this does feel like double handling. As per my hunch in the first question I guess the benefits of separating these concerns far outweigh what feels like a slightly laborious mapping process.
3. If the `LoginViewModel` calls all functionality contained within the `SessionManager` is it enough to write tests against the `LoginViewModel` only or should tests also be written specifically against the `SessionManager`?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty late, and I'm sure you've moved on.

1) moving program logic out of a view/control is always worth the extra few lines of cone that you need to write to proxy.  The point of MVVM is to encourage the separation of concerns and to provide a clear channel of data between the View/Controller and the Model via the ViewModel.

From the perspective of the View/Controller, your View Models should perform the following function:

Act as a black-box of data which your View/Controller can leverage without performing any business rules and always assume the data is correct.

Act as a conduit for user-input processing which takes that user-input without having to perform any business rules.

2) In my implementations of MVVM I try and follow this paradigm: A view/controller containing a CollectionView/TableView is a parent view, and the cells are child views.  Thus, you should have a parent ViewModel who's job is to initialize and manage child ViewModels.

In your case, you're not using a Collection/Table view, but the concept is the same.  You should be asking your parent View Model for a list of child ViewModels which you can pass into another view to leverage.  Following the point in answer #1, the parent View Model should ensure that the Child ViewModels are initialized correctly so that the child View doesn't need to worry about any data validation.

3) When testing your View Model's data validation/rules, you can stub out the Session Manager entirely and only test the View Model.  What I do is create assertions that the stubbed/mocked Session Manager functions are called appropriately in my unit test.

Comment: I have a question. I hope you could shed some light on this. Say there's an API call I make after the login to retrieve some data. I put the code related to calling the API and returning results back to the view in LoginViewModel. Down the line within the app in another view, I need call the same API and get data. Do I reference LoginViewModel in that view and call that method right then and there? I feel like this is odd because I'm referring a view model class that doesn't belong in that particular view and just for calling one method.

Comment: Do I extract these repeating methods to some kinda common view model or something?

Comment: The View Model should be only used by one view.  In your example you would have two classes, each making a call into your authentication API.  If each implementation has a significant amount of code, that may be a signal that you should wrap up the API call into a helper/integration class.  You definitely do not want business rules in your view model that don't pertain to the view.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do have the method that calls the API in a separate class. Is it okay to call this method from two different view models? The code would be duplicated and that's my concern.